# How can I fix crashing Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, 19.10

I use a Bluetooth headset and every couple of days my laptop (HP Zbook) disconnects and I cannot reconnect. When this happens there are no adapters shown. If I try `sudo service bluetooth restart` it doesn't fix the problem. The only way I can get it working is to reboot which is fast becoming a chore.

What can I do to either stop this from happening or get it working again without having to reboot?

Comment: I am also facing this issue. My bluetooth device worked fine with windows 10 and latest elementary OS but It disconnects as soon as I start playing something. I tried to power on bluetooth using terminal but gives me error. "Failed to set power on: org.bluez.Error.Failed.